# 555 circuit with high input and pulse adjustable output

Tags: 555, timer

I found a 555 timer that works with a pulsed input and gives an adjustable single pulse output.  (see below).
I need the same circuit to work with a constant high input.
8ms input high
4ms output high
4ms output low

any help appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to let the falling edge of the signal be passed to the trigger pin. You need a coupling capacitor to remove the DC element of the signal like this ([image source](https://learnabout-electronics.org/Oscillators/osc45.php)):

[image: 555 trigger]

Instead of connecting the transistor directly to the trigger pin, add a very small capacitor from the collector to the trigger pin. Note that you also need another resistor on the collector as a pull-up to make sure the capacitor will discharge when the transistor is off. Also, make sure to put the diode in so it won't damage the chip.

You need to consider these to find a suitable value for this capacitor:

- The duration of the output pulse (4ms): The capacitor must be small enough so that before this time, it's already charged and not keeping the trigger low. It's a good idea (rule of thumb) to have the time constant of the RC part around 1/10th of the monostable time (the 4ms)
- The capacitor must be big enough so the signal on the trigger pin reaches below 1/3rd of Vcc; otherwise, it can not trigger the monostable. If 1/10th of the monostable time is not enough to reach the value, you need to use a bigger capacitor.

Comment: Excellent!  this worked!  Very good! I used a 2.2uF and 1000 resistor for a time constant of 1mS.... this allows me to trigger the 555 on and still dial down the output from 8ms all the way to 1mS...

Comment: Thank you Very Much Saadat!!!!  Great Work!

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped.